# grep complete resource url within a file

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

I have to search and extract within a file addresses like these:

```
http://deimos.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/DownloadRedirectedTrackPreview/unina.it-dz.5373092572.05373092574.12739786322/enclosure.m4v
```

They are 38 links with only the last serie of digit which change.

I tried with this regexp:

```
grep -io 'http://ex[a-z.-]*/[a-z0-9+-]*/[a-z0-9.,-+]*[.m4v]'
```

it extract all the urls present in the file which point to an m4v file but not the complete url it get a partial url as follow:

```
http://deimos.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/DownloadRedirectedTrackPreview/unina.
```

Where am I wrong?

I can't figure out why it happens.

Thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: Sorry regex was grep -io 'http://d[a-z.-]/[a-z0-9+-]/[a-z0-9.,-+]*[.m4v]'

Comment: it is not very clear what you want: are you checking file names or lines within a file? Also provide a broader example to test with, together with its desired output

Comment: `.[.m4v]` won't work anyways. `[]` defines a character class. "a single character as this position can have the value `.`, `m`, `4`, or `v`. the `.m4v` should be bare, NO `[]`.

Comment: @MarcB or probably `\.m4v` instead of simple `.m4v`, to prevent the dot matching any character.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex and your extracted filename do *not* match. The filename that you list does *not* begin with:

> http://ex

Which your regex requires. you could change your regex to something more like this which would match your URL:

```
'http://(?:[a-z0-9+-]+/)*[a-z0-9+-]+\.m4v'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Jonathan it was a typing mistake while I posted in my regex was correctly used dei and not ex as written.
But the problem persisted.
Marc opened my mind.
I knew how the address starts so I tried with
grep -io 'http://dei*/*.m4v'
no success :-(
fedorqui gave the last hint, maybe the problem was a dot
so I tried
grep -io 'http://deimos.*/*.m4v' :-D
and it did the trick!

Now I have the file to give to wget to automate multiple file downloads without proprietary softwares needing.

The files are podcasts of juridic lessons released free as in freedom but only in an easy way for who would buy Apple or Microsoft (iTunes).
Now I have the file to give to wget to automate multiples file downloads without soiling my system with emulators and proprietary software.

Thanks to all indeed!!